# C# - Emgu CV dnn module - Failed to parse NetParameter file

Tags: c#, исключения, emgucv

```
public static void DetectObjects(Bitmap image)
    {
        Mat blob = DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(image.ToMat());
        _netModel.SetInput(blob);
        Mat output = _netModel.Forward();

        MessageBox.Show(output.ToString());
    }

    private static Net _netModel = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromDarknet("C:/Users/user/Downloads/yolov4-tiny.cfg.txt, C:/Users/user/Downloads/yolov4-tiny.weights");
```

Этот код бросает исключение CvException: OpenCV: Failed to parse NetParameter file: C:/Users/user/Downloads/yolov4-tiny.cfg.txt, C:/Users/user/Downloads/yolov4-tiny.weights

Для решения проблемы пытался использовать советы вроде этих: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792523/failed-to-parse-netparameter-file (Использовать абсолютный путь, скачать новые файлы darknet'а), изменений не последовало.

Также была просмотрена эта страница: https://github.com/cansik/yolo-hand-detection/issues/6, на ней тоже предлагали использовать абсолютные пути, но кроме этого спросили, не забыли ли скачать некую "модель", а позже вопрос закрыли, перед этим написав что да, действительно забыли скачать. Я не совсем понимаю что подразумевается под этой моделью что её можно было забыть скачать, может и я тоже её не скачал..

Как итог должна получится функция получающая на вход изображение и отдающая как результат список координат найденных объектов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по используемой в коде терминологии, речь идёт о DNN - deeplearning neural network, то есть нейронной сети глубокого обучения.

В таком случае, *модель* - это такой "конфиг сети", то есть набор данных, который описывает её архитектуру, конфигурацию и используемые алгоритмы обучения. Как я понял из кода, Вы ожидаете загрузить "модель с весами", то есть, уже "предобученную" нейронку.

Если Вы хотите в этом разобраться - попробуйте прочитать что нить о распознавнии на основе нейронок. Также, Вы можете исправить воопрос, написав подробнее, какую задачу  решает Ваш код.

Comment: Да, вы правы, используется DNN.

Я правильно понимаю что в случае с даркнетом, модель - это её конфигурационный файл(yolov_.cfg) и yolov_.conv.___? Искав по этому поводу информацию у меня сложилось впечатление что используя только эти два файла и набор картинок(датасет) с промаркированными на них объектами можно создать новый файл с весами. Было бы полезно узнать можно ли это сделать в коде (пока я опирался на возможность скачать релиз даркнета и использовать его для обучения).

Нить распознования - свёрточная нейросеть?

Comment: До меня дошло, что нет никакой нити, а что это сокращение от что-нибудь..
А на счет распознавании на основе нейронок я читал очень поверхностно, читал углубленно в основном про то, как это можно реализовать используя готовые библиотеки.

При этом желательно это реализовать на .NET'е, так что выбор библиотек достаточно узкий, и один из лучших вариантов - Emgu CV, имеет достаточно скудную документацию.

Comment: О вау, я только что заметил эту нелепость... я передал функции неправильные параметры. Должно было быть ReadNetFromDarknet("B:/yolov3.cfg.txt", "B:/yolov3.weights"); вместо ReadNetFromDarknet("B:/yolov3.cfg.txt, B:/yolov3.weights");   И Visual Studio мне даже не намекала на проблемы в этом месте..

Comment: Рад, что ошибка нашлась. Но когда первый раз делаешь - все равно на какие то грабли наступишь... Можете ответить сами на свой вопрос - у Вас и самостотельный правильный ответ будет, и баллов заработаете :-)